# Why is Beautiful Soup not finding the class in the HTML?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to send a AJAX request to a URL and it successfully returns the content with what I am trying to grab. However, when I try to actually pull out the specific section of the HTML it always returns None or if I try find_all it returns an empty list.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#AJAX URL to send the post to
url = "https://www.qualitycheck.org/ajax/QualityReport/ajax.aspx"

#Information being requested and BSNID vars (can be extended for additional information like GetAccreditationPrograms)
TJC_ID = '21'
payload = 'f=GetDemographicInfo&bsnid=' + TJC_ID

#Content Headers
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

#Post to TJC
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers = headers, data = payload)

#Clean up the response
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

#testing something
# tryastring = soup.find_all(string="head")
# print(tryastring)

# Pull out the "head-loc" div class only
final = soup.find('div', class_="head-loc")
print(final)

#Print results to make sure it works
# print(final.prettyify())
# print(soup.prettify())
```

If you uncomment out `# print(final.prettyify())` you will see it returns none. However if you run `print(soup.prettify())` you will get the HTML back and can see that div class in there.

I've tried so many different ways and I'm starting to think my problem isn't where I'm looking. Any ideas as to how I can have this pull just the div with the class "head-loc"? I actually want to pull both head-name and head-loc but I can figure that part out after this bridge is crossed.

I have also tried to use html.parser instead of lxml but it's the same story.

Comment: Actually you should have soup.find('div', class_=r'\"head-loc\"')

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. It ended up being because the message it was returning was JSON, not HTML. So I had to parse that first and then I could parse the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I needed to parse the JSON first and then I could parse the HTML.

```
###
    site_response: dict = response.json()
    new_html: str = site_response.get('ResponseHtml')

    ###
    # Adding our new HTML to bs4
    ###
    soup = BeautifulSoup(new_html, 'html.parser')

    # Pull out the "head-loc" div class only
    final = soup.find('div', class_="head-loc")
```